# Reading laravel terminal output using Laragon

Tags: laravel, laragon

**Actual state of art:**
I need to expose my laravel app on internal lan, and sometime I need,or I close visual studio by mistake, so I moved the project on laragon, and everything is ok.

**Need**
During the test we have implemented some `error_log()` to debug some problems.

**Problem**
Actually I cannot read the printed `error_log()` or the http request, cause opening laragon terminal is like to be on the folder with the normal terminal, I cannot read the server running terminal.

**What I want?**

I would like to use laragon, and get access to the server instance console to read the logged data printed with `error_log()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Laragon just set your config to point to the public folder of your laravel. Give it the name of sitename.test or whatever.  This will write a new line to your hosts file with the 127.0.0.1 IP.  Then if you want others to view they will have to change their host file to

```
your computers ip addy      sitename.test
```

Then open your firewall and let Laragon through on port 80 and port 3306 on your private network.

Comment: is not what I asked, my problem is how read terminal output, not how expose the site on my private network

Comment: Your question wasn't really clear so I thought that's what you were asking.  Just navigate to the root of your laravel folder with git bash or laragon terminal and you have access to all the artisian commands as well as composer commands.   Do not start a new instance with serve. Laragon already has apache running so PHP is also running.

Comment: I update my question, maybe is more comprensive, my needed is not run artisan command but is axxess to the istance of apache to read varius debug ```error_log()```